# Illegal connection port value 'mysql' not able to fetch values from database

Tags: java, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Hi I am trying to establish connections from my java to SQL workbench through the following code--

```
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        dataSource.setServerName("jdbc:mysql://localhost:XXXX/Recommendation1")
        dataSource.setUser("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("XXXXXXXX");
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("Recommendation1");
        JDBCDataModel dataModel = new MySQLJDBCDataModel(dataSource);
```

I have also included the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar in my lib directory still I am getting the following error

```
org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.common.TasteException: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal connection port value 'mysql:'
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.jdbc.AbstractJDBCDataModel.getNumThings(AbstractJDBCDataModel.java:596)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.jdbc.AbstractJDBCDataModel.getNumItems(AbstractJDBCDataModel.java:552)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.slopeone.MemoryDiffStorage.<init>(MemoryDiffStorage.java:89)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.slopeone.SlopeOneRecommender.<init>(SlopeOneRecommender.java:69)
    at com.HelloServlet1.doPost(HelloServlet1.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Primarily the reason for the error is non inclusion of mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar in lib directory of project
,But in this case what could be the reason

Thanks

Comment: I doubt if this error was because of not having the mysql connection in classpath, had it not been there, you would have received, something like NoClassDefFounError for MysqlDataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a configuration issue. Here is a sample configuration:

```
  ds.setServerName("localhost");
  ds.setPortNumber(3306);
  ds.setDatabaseName("testdb");
  ds.setUser("scott");
  ds.setPassword("tiger");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already setting database name here

```
dataSource.setDatabaseName("Recommendation1");
```

There is no need of specifying it in Server name

```
dataSource.setServerName("jdbc:mysql://localhost:XXXX/Recommendation1")
```

So, and looking at the exception, its assuming the string `'mysql'` (because its following the `:` char after `jdbc`) in the server-name to be a port. Can you try this?

```
dataSource.setServerName("localhost:XXXX");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to set the db name, as it seems that you have it in your jdbc connect URL.

Is it required?

```
dataSource.setDatabaseName("Recommendation1");
```

When you have dbname here

```
dataSource.setServerName("jdbc:mysql://localhost:XXXX/Recommendation1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
dataSource.setServerName("localhost:3306"); //Default port for MySQL
```

instead of using

```
dataSource.setServerName("jdbc:mysql://localhost:XXXX/Recommendation1");
```

Since, the `setServerName` method expects **only the name of the server along with the port** on which MySQL is running and **not entire connection string**.